# In-stream non-linear advertising with MPEG-DASH

Tags: overlay, mpeg-dash

Does MPEG-DASH provide the ability to add video overlays in the video stream (i.e. not added client side like [youtube in-video advertising](https://support.google.com/displayspecs/answer/187095?hl=en))?

e.g having an animated character walking around the screen, in front of the video.

Answer (score 0):

MPEG DASH is essentially a mechanism for efficiently streaming media files from a server to clients - it does not really care what the media files are or what you use them for.

If what you wanted was more like a banner or text, then you could have a subtitle or captions track with your video, which mp4 containers support and DASH will allow you stream.